# Apache Spark providing custom classpath

Tags: java, apache-spark, classpath

How do I supply custom classpath to spark app which is running in cluster mode (i.e. driver submits, executors executes)

`spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` option leads to more classpath conflicts.

`--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=foo/bar.jar --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=foo/bar.jar`

I used this while  using `spark-submit` I don't see this getting in effect.

Does the `foo/bar.jar` have to be present on executor host or it will also make it available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use --jars if you want to copy the jars to all executors by job itself. Otherwise you need to copy the jars.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: `--jars foo/bar.jar` just this didn't work as expected. should it go with other flags ? thanks

Comment: turns out I had to pass both the flags, `--jars` to make files available and others (mentioned in question) to make them available in classpath.